# Number of clients that can connect to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server

I am developing an application using VB and Sql Server Express edition. How many clients can connect to the system since i am using a free version of Sql Server?

Comment: Not a relevant question for StackOverflow and easy to find this using Google.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31173/max-connections-sql-server-express-could-have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Express does not limit the number of connections. But Windows 7 has a limit of 20 connections. If your database runs on a Windows 7 PC, only 20 client applications can connect to it at a time (this is not the same as 20 PCs).

Section 3e of the Windows 7 License Agreement:

> **Device Connections**. You may allow up to 20 other devices to access software installed on the licensed computer to use only File Services,
>   Print Services, Internet Information Services and Internet Connection
>   Sharing and Telephony Services

Source: [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/useterms/default.aspx)